# Why my form doesn't redirect to the link in header?

Tags: php, forms

I've searched everywhere to find a solution, but I don't have found it.
I've a form on my website, who work perfectly on localhost, but have some troubles for working well when hosted on my website server. When the user clicks on submit, if the fields are perfectly completed the email is send but there are no redirection to the link mentionned on the header('Location:'). In place to go to the page "thanks.php", the page "contact.php" is like reloaded in an empty version (full white screen).

Can you please help me to find a solution?
Thanks a lot!

**PHP code before**

```
<?PHP
  // form handler
  function validateFeedbackForm($arr)
  {
    extract($arr);

    if(!isset($name, $email, $subject, $message)) return;

    if(!$name) {
      return "DON'T PANIC! It seems, there are an error with the name.";
    }
    if(!preg_match("/^\S+@\S+$/", $email)) {
      return "DON'T PANIC! It seems, there are an error with the email address.";
    }
    if(!$subject) $subject = "Contact from website";
    if(!$message) {
      return "DON'T PANIC! It seems, there are an error with the message.";
    }

    // send email and redirect
    $to = "email@domain.com";
    $headers = $subject. " - " .$name. " " .$email. "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: ' .$email . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header('Location: ./thanks.php'); 
    exit;
  }

  // execution starts here
  if(isset($_POST['sendfeedback'])) {
    // call form handler
    $errorMsg = validateFeedbackForm($_POST);
  }
?>
```

**Form code**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <?PHP
            if(isset($errorMsg) && $errorMsg) {
                echo "<p id=\"error-msg\">",htmlspecialchars($errorMsg),"</p>\n\n";
            }
            ?>
            <input placeholder="Your name *" class="input-class ct-yourname" type="text" size="48" name="name" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
            <input placeholder="Your email address *" class="input-class ct-email" type="email" size="48" name="email" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
            <input placeholder="Subject of your message" class="input-class ct-subject" type="text" size="48" name="subject" value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['subject'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']); ?>">
            <textarea placeholder="Hey, ... *" class="input-message ct-message" name="message" cols="48" rows="8"><?PHP if(isset($_POST['message'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']); ?></textarea>
            <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" name="sendfeedback" value="Send Message">
        </form>
```

Comment: you should totally remove the form `action` - it does nothing in this example but is possibly exploitable because of `PHP_SELF`. The file `thanks.php` - is that at root level of the site?

Comment: I've removed the form `action`, nothing change without it.
Yes, `thanks.php` is at root level of the site. I've the `index.php`, my page `contact.php` (the page where I put these codes) and my page `thanks.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to OMi Shah to put me on the good way to find a solution.
Nothing was generated for me before the `header()` when I looked at my code... but in fact it wasn't totally true.

I get a little piece of code just before the PHP code block : `<!DOCTYPE php>`.
This line was just the reason of the none redirection (a loop on the same page in fact). If some other beginner got the same problem, don't forget to put no code before your PHP code.

Thanks & take care!

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. Some output is getting generated before the `header()` is called which is causing the problem. Make sure no output is generated before the `header()` is called.
2. Make sure the file in which your form is included is `utf-8` encoded, not other.
3. run `phpinfo()` and make sure that `output_buffering` is `not empty`

**Solution**: You can add `ob_start();` after the PHP opening tag `<?php` in your script as:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// other lines
```

Comment: Hi OMi Shah,

1. Nothing is generated before the `header()`, there are just the email who is send. I've tried to reverse them, but nothing change.

2. My form is utf-8 encoded.

3. I've ran a test and `output_buffering`value is "0".

I've added `ob_start();` after the PHP opening tag and nothing change.
I don't know what happen. :/